# How to only export the folder “Documents” under /home/ <users>?

Tags: nfs

I need to only export the folder "/home/%USER%/Documents" for all the users. How can I do to configure my /etc/exports file.

system: CentOS 7
  Service: NFS-server

I did try to use regex syntax in /etc/exports such as

```
/home/*/Documents    *(rw,sysc,no_roo_squash)
/home/\*/Documents    *(rw,sysc,no_roo_squash)
```

But do not work.

Comment: nfs doesn't support wildcards in path.

Comment: another option would be to make a `/exports/docs/$user/Documents` for each user, only export `/exports/docs`, and then `ln -s /exports/docs/$user/Documents ~$user/Documents` but that pushes the problems elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Since `/etc/exports` does not support wildcards you could simply run a script to create `/etc/exports` with all the needed lines automatically. The script could look like the example below and you could even run it daily via cronjob to update the exports for added or removed users.

```
grep -v "^/home/.*/Documents\b" /etc/exports > /etc/exports.new
find /home/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name Documents  \
    | sed 's/$/ *(rw,sysc,no_root_squash)/' >> /etc/exports.new
mv /etc/exports.new /etc/exports
exportfs -ra
```

Comment: Thanks  very much for the answers. but now I have another problem from the client side. I can't mount all nfs volume, it only allows me to mount the  first line.

Comment: please ignore the nfs client problem. I will write the script for the mount point of each NFS exports and will post it when it is done.